# JPA/PersistenceContext with Arquillian: Entities are not stored in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, jpa, glassfish-3, jta, jboss-arquillian

It seems odd to complain about not receiving an exception, but here we go:

Class under test:

```
/**
 * Implementation of {@link IGlossaryDataAccessObject} using JPA.
 */
@ApplicationScoped
public class JpaGlossaryDataAccessObject implements IGlossaryDataAccessObject {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * ch.diction.webportal.glossary.model.IGlossaryDataAccessObject#createGlossary
     * (java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute
    public void createGlossary(String glossaryName) {
        final GlossaryColumn column = new GlossaryColumn(DEFAULT_GLOSSARY_COLUMN_NAME);
        final GlossaryEntry entry = new GlossaryEntry(DEFAULT_ENTRY_VALUE, column);
        final GlossaryRow row = new GlossaryRow(entry);
        final Glossary glossary = new Glossary(glossaryName, row);
        entityManager.persist(glossary);
    }
// ...
}
```

Unit Test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class JpaGlossaryDataAccessObjectTest {
    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        final MavenDependencyResolver resolver = DependencyResolvers.use(MavenDependencyResolver.class)
                .loadMetadataFromPom("pom.xml");
        return ShrinkWrap
                .create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addPackage(Glossary.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(IdentityObject.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(IGlossaryDataAccessObject.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(EntityManagerProducer.class.getPackage())
                .addAsLibraries(resolver.artifact("org.jboss.seam.persistence:seam-persistence").resolveAsFiles())
                .addAsWebInfResource("ch/diction/webportal/resources/glossary/model/beans.txt", "beans.xml")
                .addAsResource("ch/diction/webportal/resources/persistence/persistence.txt", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
    }

    @Inject
    private IGlossaryDataAccessObject dao;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void testCreateGlossary() {
        final String glossaryName = "empty";
        dao.createGlossary(glossaryName);
        final List<Glossary> result = em.createQuery("SELECT g FROM Glossary g", Glossary.class).getResultList();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, result.size());
    }
}
```

This unit test, running with Arquillian on my local GlassFish 3.1.2.2 server, completes without any error or exception. Yet, when I use the debugger and stop the execution after "dao.createGlossary(...)", I can verify using MySQL Workbench that no data has actually been written to the table.

I was wondering whether the Arquillian framework is doing more than I am aware of, that it may be providing some sort of database test container, automatically rolling my transactions back after each test. Is that the case or what could possibly keep the data from being actually written to MySQL?

Thanks for any hint and best regards
Pascal

PS: For the sake of completion, here are my other test config files:

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="web-portal-test" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/web-portal-test</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="urn:java:ee"
    xmlns:security="urn:java:org.jboss.seam.security" xmlns:permission="urn:java:org.jboss.seam.security.permission"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://jboss.org/schema/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <alternatives />
    <decorators />
    <interceptors>
        <class>org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

arquillian.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />
    <container qualifier="remote-glassfish" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="adminUser">admin</property>
            <property name="adminPassword">******</property>
            <property name="adminPort">4848</property>
            <property name="adminHttps">false</property>
            <property name="remoteServerHttpPort">9005</property>
            <property name="target">server</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Update: I have been able to verify that the entities are indeed stored in the database in the live environment. So it seems that Arquillian does roll my transactions back in the unit test environment - which is weird, because in their website's guide, they're using manual SQL commands to clean the database:
http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/

Comment: Is your data-source JTA in the test environment?  If it is not, then you need to use a non-jta-data-source in your persistence.xml

Comment: It is. Test and productive environment are both configured in exactly the same manner on the same server. Yet in the production environment, the data is saved, while transactions get rolled back in the unit tests. It's perfect as it is, I'm really not complaining :-) . I'm just curious as to why that is the case.